# How To Assign Payments Received Properly In GnuCash?

Tags: gnucash

What is the "proper" way to make sure that a payment I receive for an invoice is "assigned" to that particular invoice? (I feel like many payments I have received don't get assigned to an invoice and instead it looks like the client has not paid me).

When I receive a check from a customer whom I previously sent an invoice, I go to the customer report for that customer, click on the link "Invoice" for that invoice, then click on the Pay Invoice button (very far right side).

I then do a customer report and see that there is no balance (meaning all the invoices have been paid).

But I swear at some later time those payments become "lost" in the system, meaning if I do a customer report two or three months later on, it would show that the customer has a balance due.

Am I not processing the payments the right way?

Answer (score 1):

> When I receive a check from a customer whom I previously sent an invoice, I go to the customer report for that customer, click on the link "Invoice" for that invoice, then click on the Pay Invoice button (very far right side).
>
> I then do a customer report and see that there is no balance (meaning all the invoices have been paid).

I don't process invoices using the same method you do.  Instead I go to Business -> Customer -> Process Payment.  From there I can select the applicable customer, and a list of unpaid invoices will come up.  I've never experienced the issue you've described.

On a related topic: are you posting your invoices?  From experience that has caused issues for me; when you post the invoice it should show up in your Accounts Receivable (or whichever account you've designated), and after you process the payment the A/R should go down accordingly.  When posting your invoice, you specify which account it gets posted to:

[image: Screen grab of Post Invoice window Asking for A/R Account]

So that account should show a balance once you have posted it:

[image: A/R balance]

Then, when a client pays you, your cash will go up, and A/R will go down.

Comment: Thank you, tendim. Yes, I am posting the invoices first. I guess that brings up the next question: What if I don't have an Accounts Receivable account set up? I must have not set one up when i did it originally?

Comment: I must be doing something very wrong. When I look at an account I setup (photography services) I see lots of negative balances (red letters and in parentheses), but so far, I have only being trying to track INCOME, not tracking any expenses by me. So it should show only POSITIVE numbers in the balances, shouldn't it?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include some details about the post process.

Answer (score 0):

V old post, but it came top of my search and this may be the correct answer:
[Unposting and reposting a paid invoice loses its payment](https://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/Business_Features_Issues#Unposting_and_reposting_a_paid_invoice_loses_its_payment)

EDIT

> Unposting and reposting a paid invoice loses its payment
>
> As of gnucash 2.6.0, when you unpost a paid invoice (or bill) and then
> repost it again after making corrections the invoice is no longer
> marked as paid. These have to be manually linked together again.
>
> Unfortunately gnucash 2.6.0 to 2.6.2 contained bugs that prevented
> this. In those versions your only option is to
>
> ```
> delete the payment
> delete the accompanying lot link transaction from the AR account
> reapply the payment
> ```
>
> This is cumbersome so the recommended alternative is to upgrade to
> gnucash 2.6.3 or higher. As of that version here is how you can fix
> this
>
> ```
> Open Business->Customer->Process Payment...
> Select the correct customer and optionally also the correct "Post To" account (usually the latter is ok by default)
> Now select both the unpaid invoice and the corresponding pre-payment
> This should set the amount to 0 and the transfer accounts should get greyed out
> Click Ok
> ```
>
> If the amount is not 0 that means the unpaid amount of the invoice
> doesn't match the amount of the pre-payment. How to proceed depends on
> the situation.
>
> ```
> Perhaps there was a second pre-payment to select ? You can do so and with all the lines selected click Ok.
> Or the invoice wasn't fully paid before either ? Then manually set the amount to 0 to indicate no additional payment (apart from the
> ```
>
> pre-payment) should be entered now.
> Or you have an additional payment to enter at this time ? You can set the amount to that of the additional payment and indicate which
> account was used for this payment.

Comment: Please quote from the linked article so that if the link rots, the answer still has the important information.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/86138)